# Checking whether a user has interacted with an item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table for users and items. What I would like is a way of getting all the items that a particular user has not yet completed. How would I go about this in an idiomatic Rails way efficiently? I was thinking of creating a new table called useritems that has a user_id and item_id columns. I think this is the right approach but I'm not sure how I would actually get a user's incomplete items. What is the correct activerecord syntax?

Thanks!!

Comment: is the item belongs to many users or each user has their own items.

Comment: When and how item will be completed by an user?

Comment: an item has a user who created it but ideally I would like all users to complete all the items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@trip`'s answer is right, and to elaborate on how you'd find the incomplete items, you'll need to do something like this:

---

**Join**

If you have a join model, you will only need to record the `UserItem`s which have been interacted / completed with the user (for efficiency). To find the items not completed, I'd compare the items which have been completed with the entire items list:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_items
    has_many :items, through: :user_items

    def incomplete_items
        target = self.items
        return Item.all.where('id != ?', target)
    end
end

#user_items
id | user_id | item_id | created_at | updated_at
```

This would allow you to call `@user = User.incomplete_items` to get a list of items which are not included in your `user_items`join model

Comment: I don't totally understand how the target is working here. How does `id != target` work?

Comment: Oh wait I understand now. That makes sense! If these tables are large, will this still perform decently?

Comment: Probably not - which is why I am always tentative about putting this kind of thing out there (it's more an idea than a proven method). It's where I'd start - if you get a result, you can refactor to make more efficient

Comment: Awesome! I just got this to work with my code!! Thank you so much Rich! One thing though is that there is a small typo. The line should be `return Item.all.where('id !=', target)` I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Well UserItem is the join table. And you can add an additional attribute to it for `:complete`

```
class User < ActiveRecord
  has_many :items, through: :user_items
  scope :incomplete, -> { joins(:user_items).where('user_items.complete = ?', false) }
end

class Item < ActiveRecord
  has_many :users, through: :user_items
end

class UserItem < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item
end
```

And your code could be something like this :

```
User.find(x).incomplete
```

Hmm.. you might have to do something a little more like..

```
User.find(x).incomplete.items
```

I didn't test this..

---

If that scope doesn't work.. maybe try an outer join.. Again, just guessing :

```
scope :incomplete, joins('left outer join user_items on user.id=user_items.user_id').where('user_items.complete is ?', [nil, false])
```

Comment: So the way that I have done it so far is whenever a user has completed something I create an item in the join table is this the wrong approach?